# direct messages in flask python

Tags: python, flask, message, dm

so I'm  developing python flask app where users can see other user's profile then they can click on a bottom where they can send real time direct messages using. (like direct messages in other apps).

can someone lead me to w website or source to start with.

Dose even flask can do that ?

BIG Thanks in advance.

Comment: With flask you can implement this ideas. Have you already written a Hello World program with flask or could you even tell how familiar you are with flask.

Comment: im   familiar with flask but this is my first time implementing this idea in flask I have done it in java - dj and others !!

Comment: Then I would go for the answer given below ;)

Answer (score 2):

For this, you will need to use sockets. `Flask-SocketIO` is what you should use for this. Here's a decent guide on how to set it up, specifically for using for chat.

https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d

It's for building a chat room, not private messages, but I think it's a good base and you can work out what you need to change to do private messages from here.

Comment: Thanks for your help - Yes I have checked this before. I think I can use the flask-login technique. then create URL for each user then I don't know what next ! LOL